# Print the namespace of the current context in Kubernetes

Tags: kubectl, jsonpath

I'd like to print the namespace of the current context in Kubernetes.

`oc config view -o json` returns the following output (shortened for readability)

```json
{
    "kind": "Config",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "contexts": [
        {
            "name": "pp2-review/master-ocp-internal-company-com:443/Philippe",
            "context": {
                "cluster": "master-ocp-internal-company-com:443",
                "user": "Philippe",
                "namespace": "pp2-review"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "pp2-master/master-ocp-internal-company-com:443/Philippe",
            "context": {
                "cluster": "master-ocp-internal-company-com:443",
                "user": "Philippe",
                "namespace": "review"
            }
        }
    ],
    "current-context": "pp2-review/master-ocp-internal-company-com:443/Philippe"
}
```

I'd like to return `pp2-review`. The namespace of the current context.

`oc config view -o "jsonpath={\$.current-context}"` returns `pp2-review/master-ocp-internal-company-com:443/Philippe`.

`oc config view -o "jsonpath={.contexts[?(@.name==\"pp2-review/master-ocp-internal-company-com:443/Philippe\")].context.namespace}"` returns `pp2-review`.

Combining them into `oc config view -o "jsonpath={\$.contexts[?(@.name==\$.current-context)]}"` returns nothing.

Is there some other way besides executing the first command and putting its return value in the second?

Comment: I cannot try this but I think this path express should work: `$..[?(@.name==$.current-context)].context.namespace`

Comment: Executing it returns `error: error executing jsonpath "{$..[?(@.name==$.current-context)].context.namespace}": Error executing template: … is not array or slice and cannot be filtered.`

Comment: Welp, it looks like kubectl's Golang JSONPath implementation does not support this.

Comment: Too bad. Thank you for trying.

Comment: Other answers get close to this, but don't put it all together: `oc config view --minify -o jsonpath='{.contexts[0].context.namespace}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because JSON path doesn't seem to work. I searched and found a solution using Go templates:

```sh
> oc config view -o go-template='{{$currentContext := index . "current-context"}}{{- range .contexts -}}{{- if eq .name $currentContext -}}{{ .context.namespace}}{{- end -}}{{- end -}}'
review
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple **bash command substitution** should do the job:

```
oc config view -o "jsonpath={.contexts[?(@.name==\"$(oc config view -o "jsonpath={\$.current-context}")\")].context.namespace}"
```

Comment: I know. But if possible I'd like to do it with one call to `oc`.

Answer (score 1):

This command will display your current context and namespace. The `--minify` flag means only details about the current context will be return:

```
kubectl config view --minify
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`kubectl config view --minify | grep namespace:`